# Copy a large file over an unreliable link

Tags: vpn, rsync

This isn't really a question about programming, but it is a question about working as a programmer.  I hope this is an appropriate forum for this question.

I work from home.  My Windows XP based laptop connects through a VPN to the network of my employer.  Occasionally, I need to download a large file (~2.5 GB) that is shared on a network drive.  While it's possible to just drag-and-drop the file using Windows explorer, to copy the file, there is a good chance that the VPN will timeout or my internet connection will flake out at some point during the transfer.

So what I'm looking for is a way to copy a large file that supports resuming if the connection fails.  I initially tried to use rsync from within cygwin, but I don't think I had the right set of options.

I was doing "rsync -aP src_file_path dest_file_path".  It would download correctly if the transfer completed without error, but if it crashed, when I issued the command again, it would start downloading the entire file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might also try robocopy, an xcopy replacement that ships in Vista, and is available in the Windows XP Resource Kit.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

Robocopy contains options (/Z) for copying files in "restartable" (read: resumable) mode.

Comment: I've been a robocopy user for years and I didn't know about the /Z option.  I've just spent about 10 days failing to copy a 2GB file over an unreliable ADSL line.  I added the /Z to my robocopy call and it worked a treat.  Yippee.

Answer (score 8):

Your rsync command line looks correct (`-P` is needed to keep partially transfered files), you however have to make sure that you are actually using rsync for the data transfer itself by specifing a remote path:

```
rsync -aP juser@server:/tmp/data some_directory
```

If both paths refer to the local filesystem (even when one of them is a network filesystem), rsync can't use its delta transfer and will transfer the full file.

Answer (score 5):

I like [teracopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php). Works like a charm and can integrate with windows explorer as well. Great for large files 10x better than windows. It is free but has a paid version.

Comment: Oh, that's better. Forgot about that one. It does resume.

Comment: I have tried using Teracopy a number of times over the past year.  I think that it might be an adequate tool for copying a large number of small files, but I haven't been able to get the resume support to work properly, so it has been useless to me.  Robocopy looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

You could try BITS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service , specifically the WinBITS GUI: http://www.darvin.de/english/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Being lateral, you could try setting something up with [Live mesh](https://www.mesh.com/welcome/default.aspx), if you have the appropriate permissions and security.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but doesn't Mesh have a single file size limit?