# How to Copy From Network Drive to Desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows, vpn

I have a windows 7 machine and I need to get an 8gb(virtual machine file) file from a network drive. I have to connect through a vpn and then copy it.

I have tried to copy the file to my desktop twice but both times I lost connection to the vpn for a brief second or my internet connection.

So when that happen there goes hours and hours of waiting for the file to download. Is there something I can quickly setup or use so that when I lose connection for 5 seconds I don't have to restart and try to recopy it over?

Comment: Please provide more detail about the network itself.  For instance why do you need to connect to a VPN in order to connect to the network.  I assume you are connecting to a coperate networking at remote location?  Have you tried to archive the file?

Answer (score 3):

RoboCopy built in to Windows 7 is supposed to be able to resume after a lost network connection.

From a command prompt (Start, Run, "Cmd") enter 'Robocopy \Server\Folder\File.xxx C:\Downloads\File.xxx"

That should do it, you may need to authorise if the remote server users a different log on to your current one, that can be done with "net use \Server\Folder /User:Sam password".

Answer (score 1):

It might be a [duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/48218/copy-a-large-file-over-an-unreliable-link), this super user question seems to answer your need. You can try [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy).